# Find all folders starting with a character

Tags: regex, bash

I want to find the sum of the size of all the folders in my root directory csv, that begin with a capital or lower case h. My current command only gives all the files that contain an h, not beginning with. What am I doing wrong?

```
find csv -iname ^h -type d | du -h
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line will print all directories starting with `h`, and sends the output to `du -bc` :

```
find csv -iname 'h*' -type d -exec du -bc '{}' +
```

The command `du -bc` will print all sizes of subdirectories in bytes and in the end show the total bytesize.

If you just want to see the total, you can pipe it to `tail -1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pipeline to get sum of all folders that start with `h` or `H`:

```
find csv -type d -iname 'h*' -print0 |
xargs -0 du -s |
awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum}'
```

Note that output will be in `kb`. If you want to get `mb` or `gb` them change expression in `END` block.